# If statement inside if statement not funcitoning

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make a game to help me get better at JS, and I'm trying to set a system where it will not repeat the clear the interval, effectively starting over the loading bar if a certain value is met, but it constantly clears the interval even though said value is not met. You can see the if statement inside of the first, but it seems to be overruling the interior if statement. Any help? Again please excuse me if its obvious I'm very new to this.

```
    function click_01() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('trash_02');
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    var width = 1;
    function frame(){
       if (width >= 100) {
            if (man_01 === 0) {
              clearInterval('id');
            }
            elem.style.width = 0 + '%';
            width = 0;
            cash = cash + (Math.pow(trashcan, 1.7));
            update();
            document.getElementById('trash').disabled = false;
       } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById('trash').disabled = true;
       }
      }
    }
    <div id="man_01">
    <div id="abs" onclick="man_01c()">
        <p href="" id="man_01a">Trash Manager</p>
        <p id="man_01b">$200</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because width is never greater than 100? That condition is never met so it jumps straight to the else.

Comment: it is met after 100x10 ms, then it turns to the else statement, but when man_01 is 1, it shouldnt clear the interval which will reset the process automatically, while normally you have to click.

Comment: actually, since it isnt at 100, it does width++; which eventually sets it to 100 which when it is, should take into consideration the interior if statement. so you are right, but when it goes to the original, it should consider the if.

Comment: Console.log(man_01) after the width condition is met and see what it is, if it equals 0 when it shouldn't then you know where the issue lies

Comment: check the question for HTML

Comment: Man_01 will always be 0 because it's a HTML element, you can't store variables in them, check my answer

Comment: no actually, that isnt the issue, i have figured it out, it is because i was referring to clearInterval(id) as a string instead of a var, thank you for your time anyway!